# How to get Filter Option values in Pivot Table using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

```
Sub Macro11()
Dim A As Worksheet, B As Worksheet
    Dim ALastRow As Long, BLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim datarange As Range
    Dim myString As String
    Dim oldString As String
    Dim y As Long
    
    Set A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vendor")
    
    ALastRow = A.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name"). _
        CurrentPage = "(All)"
         For x = 1 To ALastRow
            With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable5").PivotFields("Principal Vendor Name")
            myString = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value
            y = x - 1
            oldString = ActiveSheet.Cells(y, 1).Value
            .PivotItems(oldString).Visible = False
        
            .PivotItems(myString).Visible = True
        End With
    Next x
End Sub
Sub arc_vlookup_longuom()

    Dim A As Worksheet, B As Worksheet
    Dim ALastRow As Long, BLastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim datarange As Range
    Dim myString As String
    
    Set A = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Vendor")
    
    ALastRow = A.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    
    For x = 1 To ALastRow
      
         myString = ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value
         
         Debug.Print myString
    
    
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: It seems that you included your code (good) but forgot to ask a specific question (not so good). Please explain the issue.

Comment: What is your code intended to do, and what is it doing or not doing that's different from that?